# Hyperlinks between Word documents in document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, document, hyperlink, word

I'm creating a document library with a bunch of Word documents that will contain various hyperlinks to bookmarks in other documents.

I.e "Psychedelic drugs (**Click here** for more information) greatly increases XYZXYZ"

Now, I had no problem doing this locally on my own computer, but when I do it in sharepoint it will only open the document, ignoring the bookmark placed in the adress field.

Could this have something to do with warning that appears whenever I click the hyperlink (*Opening file. Some files can contain viruses or other harmful malware etc etc*).

Somewhat of a vague question, but I hope you guys can help me out!